# Trying to print a USPS Sort barcode on a PDF document

Tags: fonts, barcode

I'm trying to print a US Postal Sort barcode on a PDF document in GeneXus X Evo3 U16 (Windows) and it only prints text and not the barcode. I have tried this in GeneXus 17 U16 as well and get the same results.

I created a small procedure to test with one line to test the barcode print. I changed the PDFReport.ini. It is as follows

```
Barcode128AsImage= true
SearchNewFontsOnce= true
Version= 1.0.0.0
DEBUG= false
OutputFileDirectory= .
RunDirection= 2
DottedStyle= 1;2
LineCapProjectingSquare= true
ServerPrinting= false
Embeed Fonts= true
LongDotDashedStyle= 6;2;1;2
AdjustToPaper= true
JustifiedTypeAll= false
TopMargin= 0.75
Leading= 2
BottomMargin= 6
LongDashedStyle= 6;2
LeftMargin= 0.75
SearchNewFonts= false
DashedStyle= 4;2
 
[Fonts Location (MS)]
USPSIMBStandard= c:\windows\fonts\USPSIMBStandard.ttf

[Embeed Fonts]
USPSIMBStandard= true
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The PDFReport isn't formatted like this. Stack overflow reformatted it as a block.

Comment: Could the `[Embeed Fonts]` be part of the problem?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It appears to be mis-spelled.  Should be either Embed or Embeded?

Comment: I have it spelled the way that GeneXus spelled it in their documentation. I changed it to embed and I received the same result.